# Java stream giving 'incomparable types: int and String' even after int conversion to String

Tags: java

I have a Java class that squares all the numbers between 0 and a given number. Each squared number is then converted to a string using String.valueOf(number). A given digit is also converted to a String. The squared number and the given digit (both converted to strings) are then passed into a function that is supposed to count the number of times that the digit appears in the squared number as String using a stream. However, when this comparison takes place Java gives me the error:

```
incomparable types: int and String
      int count = squareString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == criticalDigit).count();
```

Why does this stream given me this error when the ints have already been converted to strings and how can I successfully count the number of times a string digit appears in a string int?

The code I currently have is:

```
import java.util.stream.*;

public class CountDig {

    public static int nbDig(int n, int d) {
      int[] squaredNumbers = new int[n];
      int number = 0;
      String strV = String.valueOf(d);
      int totalCount = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        number = i * 2;
        String squaredString = String.valueOf(number);
        totalCount += occurrenceChecker(squaredString, strV);
    }
      return totalCount;
    }

    public static int occurrenceChecker(String squareString, String criticalDigit) {
      int count = squareString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == criticalDigit).count();
      return count;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chars() return IntStream So ch is integer in Lambda expression

If d on method nbDig is in '0' to '9', below code works.

```
squareString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == criticalDigit.charAt(0)).count()
```

If not you should change algorithm.

---

ok If the d can be multiple digit. below code help you.

```
squareString.chars().filter(ch -> criticalDigit.indexOf(ch) != -1).count()
```

Comment: it's not possible to just convert a String to a char and pass it in as the second value?

Comment: i don't think that works either: "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int"

Comment: @Dog I edit my answer. please check it. But you say long?

Comment: @Dog you want n * m matching GBlodgett answer is better.
n: squareString
m: criticalDigit

Comment: for a single digit this gives the same error: squareString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == criticalDigit.charAt(0)).count()

Comment: It's successfully tested on Java 8. Oh maybe you should case return value of count() as int.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're trying to return an `int` (`count`) from a function with a `String` return type:

public static String occurrenceChecker(String squareString, String criticalDigit)

Second in this line:

```
  int count = squareString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == criticalDigit).count();
```

`criticalDigit` is a `String` and `ch` is a `int`. ([`chars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) returns "*an IntStream of char values from this sequence*")

An alternate method would use the [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) function to count the a given `String`:

```
public static String occurrenceChecker(String squareString, String criticalDigit) {
  int temp = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while(squareString.indexOf(criticalDigit, temp) != -1) {
      count++;
      temp = squareString.indexOf(criticalDigit, temp) + criticalDigit.length();
  }
  return Integer.toString(count);
}
```

This is assuming that you are wanting to return the `String` representation of the result

Comment: is it possible to just convert a String to a char and pass it in as the second value?

Comment: @Dog Is the number going to be multiple digits?

Comment: i think it possibly could

Comment: actually no i don't think so. in that case it'd be necessary to break down the original integer i i think. it was just odd to me that i couldn't pass the char into the method.

Comment: @Dog I edited my post with an alternate method that should work even if it is multiple digits